# request.is_ajax not executing render_to_response django

Tags: python, ajax, django, django-views

I am having a small django view that responds with an dict, on an ajax call . Here is the code below :

Ajax Call :

```
var getdata = function(e){
                var id = this.id;
                console.log(id);
                $.ajax({
                    url:'/editcontact/',
                    method :'POST',
                    data :{
                        'name' : id,
                    },
                    success:function(){
                        console.log("success");
                    },
                    error:function(status){
                        console.log (status);
                    }
                });
            };
            $("button").on('click',getdata);
```

views.py

```
if request.is_ajax:
print "comes here"
value1 = request.GET['name']
print value1
data = dbs.objects.filter(cname=value1)
print data
return render_to_response("editcontact.html",{"data":data}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

the code is executing till print data, but the render_to_response is not working.

Comment: tell me what error you are getting ?

Comment: No error !! neither in ajax call nor in views ...

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you to return response in json format. that will solve your problem.
you can take help from below given code and can change your views.py

```
import json
if request.is_ajax:
    print "comes here"
    value1 = request.GET['name']
    print value1
    data = dbs.objects.filter(cname=value1)
    json = simplejson.dumps(data)
    return HttpResponse(json, mimetype='application/json')
```